# example.com/en/blabla to behave like example.com/blabla?lang=en

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

`example.com/en` should behave as `example.com?lang=en`

`example.com/fr` should behave as `example.com?lang=fr`

`example.com/XX` should behave as `example.com?lang=XX`

`example.com/en/some-page.php` should behave as `example.com/some-page.php?lang=en`

Something I tried which fails (but is almost there):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/\?lang=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ $2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`example.com/en` shows 404 not found BUT `example.com/en/index.php` and `example.com/en/some-age.php`, `example.com` work.

How to make it work when it's simply `example.com/en` ?

Basically all I need to do is make example.com/fr behave as example.com/index.php?lang=fr, that's the ONLY case that's not working (when going to example.com/XX).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the followin rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /?lang-en [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*?)\.php$ /$1.php?lang-en [NC,L]
```

Comment: There was a typo in the description, like the title says though, lang is a GET param like ?lang=en. Using these rules leads to a 404 when I go to example.com/en

Comment: Basically all I need to do is make `example.com/fr` behave as `example.com/index.php?lang=fr`, that's the ONLY case that's not working (when going to `example.com/XX`).